# How To fetch Email Address as per Username

Tags: android, sqlite

i want to fetch usermail from Sqlite Data when i select username i tried this code getting error

```
      android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: royal (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT userName, compMail FROM Records WHERE userName= royal
```

DBController.java

```
public String returnickname(long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] coloumns = new String[] { COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE,COLUMN_COMP_MAIL };//calling elements in an array
        Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_NAME, coloumns,COLUMN_NAME + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String nickname = c.getString(2); // since name is  in position 2 ie 3rd coloumn
            return nickname;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

VehicleReceipt.java

```
 if (spinner.getId()== R.id.insu_comp_spinner) {

            String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            long l=Long.parseLong(label);
            String returnedname=controller.returnickname(l);
            editICM.setText(returnedname);
```

I want to Fetch Data by Spinner Selection

For Example : select contact_no where name ='ram';

when i select ram set rams contact_no to Edit text.

Comment: You have not shown the correct code; a `long` variable cannot have the value `royal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the exception you posted says:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: royal (code 1)

If you put `String` values in your query without quotes, the database will assume it to be a column name.

Your compiled query is:

```
SELECT userName, compMail FROM Records WHERE userName=royal
```

which should have been:

```
SELECT userName, compMail FROM Records WHERE userName='royal'
```

---

Wrap the values in quotes `'`. Try changing your query to:

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_NAME, coloumns,COLUMN_NAME + "='" + l + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

That will make your method look like:

```
public String returnickname(long l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] coloumns = new String[] { COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE,COLUMN_COMP_MAIL };//calling elements in an array
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_NAME, coloumns,COLUMN_NAME + "='" + l + "'", null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String nickname = c.getString(2); // since name is  in position 2 ie 3rd coloumn
        return nickname;
    }
    return null;
}
```

You may read about the basics of SQLite queries here: [SQLite SELECT Query](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_select_query.htm)

Comment: whould u like to make correct it . ? bcz  i cant get it

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Do you want me to elaborate more?

Comment: i m newbie i want to fetch data on working time . when i choose username that time i want to set usermail to edittext .

Comment: You maybe a newbie, but you have the common sense to replace one line with another right?

Comment: l is variable i cant write it as  like ' '  , " " , its send the choosen value to Query but query could not fire .

Comment: Thanks Bro ... Its Working

Comment: "_If you don't worry about it and just copy paste it in your code, it will work_"  This advice will just perpetuate the problem. OP _needs_ to do some basic research so they can _understand_ what was wrong.

Comment: hmm I agree, I shouldn't advice that.